# Writing MapReduce job to concurrently download files?

Tags: hadoop, oozie, cloudera-cdh

Not sure if this is a suitable use case for MapReduce: Part of the OOZIE workflow I'm trying to implement is to download a series of files named with sequential numbers (e.g. 1 through 20). I wanted those files to be downloaded simultaneously (5 files at a time), so I created a python script that creates 5 text files as follows:

```
1.txt: 1,2,3,4
2.txt: 5,6,7,8
3.txt: 9,10,11,12
4.txt: 13,14,15,16
5.txt: 17,18,19,20
```

Then for the next step of the workflow, I created a `download.sh` shell script that consumes a comma-separated list of numbers and download the requested files. In the workflow, I setup a **streaming** action in Oozie and used the directory that contains files generated above as input (`mapred.input.dir`) and used download.sh as the mapper command and "cat" as the reducer command. I assumed that Hadoop will spawn a different mapper for each of the input files above.

This seems to work sometimes, it would download the files correctly, but sometimes it just get stuck trying to execute and I don't know why. I noticed that this happen when I increase the number of simultaneous downloads (e.g. instead of files per txt file, I would do 20 and so forth).

So my question is: Is this a correct way to implement parallel retrieval of files using MapReduce and OOZIE? If not, how is this normally done using OOZIE? I'm trying to get my CSV files into the HDFS prior to running the Hive script and I'm not sure what the best way would be to achieve that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After looking deeper into this, it seems that creating an Oozie "Fork" node would be the best approach. So I created a fork node, under which I created 6 shell actions that executes download.sh and take the list of file numbers as an argument. So I ended up modifying the python script so it outputs the file numbers that need to be downloaded to STDOUT (instead of saving them on HDFS). I had oozie capture that output and then pass them as arguments to the download.sh forks.

Cloudera Hue interface does not provide a way to create fork nodes (at least not that I was able to find) so I downloaded the workflow.xml file and added the fork nodes myself and then re-imported it as a new workflow.